# Any drawbacks of developing Drupal on Windows?

Tags: drupal

I'm going to setup a website for the family.  I've done the research and decided Drupal is best for me.  I'm trying to decide what to use for a development platform.  After reviewing several options, the two best ones for me are running Drupal on my Windows 7 PC, or installing Ubuntu on a laptop and run it there.  Either option would run the same environment (Apache, MySQL, PHP).  My Windows PC is on a nice large desk with a comfortable chair and nice monitor, so I'm leaning towards that.

My research showed there's some limitations with Drush on Windows.  So, I'm wondering:  is Drush really necessary (I've read everything can be done via GUI--is that true)?  Also, is there anything else that won't "work right" under a Windows environment?

Thanks!

Jim

Comment: I have been developing Drupal sites on windows for 10 years. I use cygwin to emulate linux commands, sometimes I just use wampserver and sometimes I use virtual machines with virtualbox. Also Windows 10 now has the "Windows Subsystem for Linux" for liniux commands. You don't say what version of Drupal you will be using or your IT experience.

Comment: Having said that, it would probably simplify things a bit if you did it on a Linux machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drush isn't necessary and most of the work will be done from site back-end. Can be handy sometime, but absolutely it's not "must have".

And if you are going to host your site on linux machine it's somehow more natural to develop there. Basically it's "industrial standard" and for every issue you could face you'll find an answer easier for linux. Vagrant is good (and quick) solution - go for it.

Also even Drupal 8 is newest and heavily advertised I don't think it's really ready yet. A lot of modules are in alpha/beta state so IMHO Drupal 7 is still better solution.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  It seems to coincide with my research.  So far, from what I've read, everything is "the same" regardless of Windows vs Linux, so I'm not expecting it to be harder to get questions answered.  And, because people are bringing it up, I decided not to use a virtual environment--in my personal opinion, I saw little value in adding that complication.  So, for me, it's either a separate Linux box, or Windows.  Thanks again.

Comment: There are no much difference regarding Drupal it self on Linux/Windows (if any at all), but setting web server is different and you'll easier find answer regarding that. I would go for Ubuntu since it's somehow the most (begginer) user friendly distribution. But if you are good with Windows then it's totally ok. too, of course.

Comment: I finished reading the User Guide.  Every example uses the web interface ifor configuration (with some optional Drush commands).

Answer (score 0):

You could also look into Vagrant to virtualize your dev environment. You would code and work in Windows and run Drupal in Linux, for example.

Also, you could use Drush within the virtualized environment. There are already configs and machines specifically tailored for Drupal dev, this being one of the most popular: https://github.com/geerlingguy/drupal-vm

Almost everything that Drush does can be done via GUI though. Drush, in short, lets you issue commands without the need to navigate through the menus and such.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  "Almost everything...".  Are you saying you NEED Drush to handle some maintenance that can't be done via the GUI (or bash shell)?  If so, please state what they are.  Thanks.

Comment: At the end of the day Drush is just a shell wrapper for typical things. You can do all that Drush does by other means (Drupal interface, database managers, etc.). What I meant is that there are commands that Drush does that require multiple steps or are cumbersome when using the interface (they are few and far between), but you can go by without Drush just fine. I made several Drupal sites before discovering Drush without any problems. It's not required at all. Sorry If my wording was misleading. Frankly, I use Drush the most for caches and backups and all of this is easy via GUI/DB tools.

Comment: From my experience drush is useful at some uncommon situations. I.e. don't remember why, but I couldn't dump database from console with mysql dump, but I could do that from drush. Or site was messed up somehow and I couldn't access backend, but after I cleared the cache from drush everything was back to normal. It's also good for updates since drush is checking when you are updating one module that maybe some other has to be updated as well.